# Installed w10, got only directx 9Ex

Tags: windows-10, video-encoding, directx

I installed w10, 
dxdiag is showing that it has directx 9Ex

What happened to dx 12, 11.1 11.0 or even 10?

how can it bundle such an older dx version?

1. If higher dx versions are there in the installation pen drive, how can I extract the installations files from there and install them?
2. I also have w8 and w7 installations, so how can I copy a higher dx version from those o.s. to w10?

ADD: 27 April 2016

I also am not in to gaming, so don't need higher dx for that.
I use ChrisTV to watch TV on my pc using a TV Tuner.
ChrisTV shows lines and haziness that distracts, so taking recomendation of christv site, I download WMEncoder_64bit_v9 
which, on running, is giving the error that 
"it requires directx media 8.1, so can't run."

Even when my dx is 9E something it doesn't recognize that, probably it needs clearcut 9.0 written there.
So I tried to upgrade dx just to be able to run WMencoder.

the question changes to how to make WMencoder run on my box which requires dx 8.1 or higher, when I already have dx 9E.

Can I downgrade dx to dx 9.0 so that the software recognizes it and runs?
Thanks.

Comment: Windows 10 by default has DX12 installed, it cannot be installed, DX9 is installed only if the end user, which would be yourself, installs it.  DX12 and DX9 are separate installations.  You cannot "extract" the DX12, only Windows 10 supports DX12, so it wouldn't do you any good.  If you want a more indepth answer, provide the dxdiag report, edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is one of two things:

1. Your computer's graphic card is too old for DX10+. This should only happen with really old cards, but it's possible. I think Win10 does not support some older WDDM drivers, so even if you had DX10 in Vista or so, you may not be able to get it with Win10 if the driver was not updated for Win10.
2. Your graphics driver is not installed, or is disabled for some reason. Check in Device Manager for driver problem, and/or get it from the manufacturer's site.

Posting the full output of the `dxdiag` program might help to diagnose the problem more accurately.

Comment: This appears to be more of a comment, since you are asking them to provide information, then an actual answer.